# ssh connection working in one computer but not another

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I'm trying to ssh to my home lab ubuntu server (17.10). I used to ssh from my regular laptop and used to work fine. Suddenly it stopped working. I tried reinstalling the SSH server..even the OS but the problem persisted. When I tried ssh from a different laptop I was able to connect. I'm using putty client on both the laptops.
I don't know what could have changed and how to troubleshoot.For now, I could isolate the issue to the laptop. How do I resolve this?

Comment: What is the output of ssh when it 'stops working'?

Comment: network error : connection timed out. Thats the error am getting.

Comment: Read `man ssh`, and use `ssh -v` to get more information about the failure.

Comment: What is the output of `ping <your home lab server>`?

Comment: Pinging 192.168.178.27 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.178.27: bytes=32 time=290ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.178.27: bytes=32 time=107ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.178.27: bytes=32 time=101ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.178.27: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.178.27:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 21ms, Maximum = 290ms, Average = 129ms